# 403 forbidden error cgi

Tags: html, c, cgi

I have a public html folder with my html pages and CGI script written in c. Within that, I have my  cgi-bin folder with my GCI executable. However when I try to access my cgi page in my browser, it gives me the forbidden error. I'm using firefox and a linux system. I've looked around for the correct permissions but resources often advise different combinations. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

With a FTP client, or with console, check the rights to execute for the file. The apache process sould be able to execute it.

If this is right, and it still not work, then you have to properly configure the server.

Answer (score 0):

As per your design ( 8 years ago on 2021), you did not provide permission for your cgi directory in the web server (possibly APACHE) configuration file.

Example in *nix:
Lets say your cgi-bin directory is actually is in /usr/home/your-name/cgi-bin

Then you have to add this to your that domains cgi section of your servers (ie Apache 2.4++) configuration file.

```
   ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/usr/local/www/ceo/cgi-bin/"
    <Directory "/usr/local/www/ceo/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

And of course don't forget to turn on CGI module ( remove the #).